# Are $x^2$ and $x^2 + 1$ asymptotic?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

You can see that as the curves go towards infinity, they come pretty close to each other, with the distance between them decreasing continuously. But I haven't seen any source saying they're asymptotic. Even my math teacher says it's an exception. So are they actually asymptotic or they're a mathematical exception?

Comment: "with the distance between them decreasing continuously" I'd say their distance stays 1 for the same x. If you're talking about minimum Euclidean distances, then you're already assuming that we first define y=f(x)=x^2 and y=g(x)=x^2+1 to be plotted as curves on the same cartesian graph.

Comment: @aviator No, the difference of their values stays $1$, but their distance decreases.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said difference. I don't think distances are relevant when talking about asymptotic limits, but differences between values are.

Comment: @aviator- why doesn't distance matter when talking about asymptotic limits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are asymptotically equivalent.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty}1+\frac{1}{x^2} = 1$$

In general, two nonzero polynomials are asymptotically equivalent if and only if they have the same leading coefficient and the same degree.

Comment: How does it follow from the limit being $1$ that the  distance between the functions tends to zero?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I don't think that asymptotic implies convergence to the same values.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe "Asymptotically equivalent" means precisely that the ratio tends to $1$. It doesn't say anything about the absolute difference between the functions; only the relative difference.

Comment: Then that means x +1 and x are asymptotically equivalent right? So does that mean they tend toward each other as they go to infinity?

Comment: @PatrickStevens As one finds in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition OTOH, the definition of asymptote in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote reads: "More generally, one curve is a curvilinear asymptote of another (as opposed to a linear asymptote) if the distance between the two curves tends to zero as they tend to infinity" So two function may be asymptotically equivalent, but not one of them is an asymptote of the other as in $f(x)=x$ and g(x)=x+1$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Indeed.